# Android Calendar Provider: How can I delete my own local calendars?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am just learning how to work with the Android Calendars. So far, I am able to display the info about existing calendars. I can also create my own local calendars -- the test code like:

```
private void createCalendarTest()
{
    Uri.Builder builder = Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    builder.appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
           .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "private")
           .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);

    Uri uri = builder.build();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Calendars.NAME, "TEST");
    values.put(Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, "Calendar named TEST");
    values.put(Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, false);
    values.put(Calendars.VISIBLE, true);

    getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
}
```

Actually, I can create many calendars that differ only in `_ID`. I have read elsewhere that I can create a calendar only when using the sync adapter. Now, how can I delete the calendar? I expect the URI must also contain the sync adapter info, and the `_ID` of the deleted calendar. I tried the following code, but I was unsuccessful:

```
private void deleteCalendarTest()
{
    Uri.Builder builder = Calendars.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    builder.appendPath("6")   // here for testing; I know the calender has this ID
           .appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
           .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "private")
           .appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);

    Uri uri = builder.build();

    getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
    Toast.makeText(this, "??? deleteCalendarTest() not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find any fix for the issue? I'm in the same situation of you!

Comment: No, I did not fix it. That part of the project was stopped, and I did not continue to search for the solution.

Comment: I found a solution and I answered to the question... maybe it will help someone else!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading with more attention the documentation, i found out you should add to the content values the following fields too:

```
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "private");
values.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE,CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
```

Then everything else should be fine and you should be able to delete the inserted calendar! ;)

Comment: I added all these parameters to create a calender but still not able to delete the local calender which i create programitically from the application

Comment: If you use the fields I mentioned for calendar creation and you append to the ContentProvider's URI the three query parameters used by @pepr, you shouldn't have problems. Maybe there's something wrong in your code. Anyway, the documentation helps a lot: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Answer (score 3):

This Kotlin solution worked for me:

```kotlin
val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, calendarId.toLong())

contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null)
```

I'm removing the calendar with the application (not a SyncAdapter) so there's no need to append any query parameters. Just append the calender's id to the content uri and use a ContentResolver to delete the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

"andrea-rinaldi" was right. The below code snippet worked for me. The "calendarHandler" is an instance of the helper class that extends AsyncQueryHandler, the one you used to create the calendar.

```
Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
            .build();
calendarHandler.startDelete(0,-1,calUri,null,null);
```